# Why does the page flash all green (in react Rendering chrome addon) when changing anything in redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've created a simple app to test what part of the document gets rerendered when I add items to an array and then use `.map` in react. To manage the state I use redux. To check what gets rerendered I use the react chrome addon with the option `Paint flashing` selected.

So I expect that when I dispatch an action from a component that modifies the store, only the components connected to that part of the store would flash green. Instead, the whole screen flashes green followed by every single component that will also flash green.

Seems like anything under `<Provider />` will just update on any change inside redux store.

I've already tried `PureComponent`, managing `shouldComponentUpdate`, React.memo for the function component.

My index file looks like:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import reducers from "./store/reducers";

import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

const store = createStore(reducers);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

And my App file:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";

import ListComp from "./components/ListComp";
import ListFunc from "./components/ListFunc";
import ButtonMore from "./components/ButtonMore";

export class App extends Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
          <a
            className="App-link"
            href="https://reactjs.org"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Learn React
          </a>
        </header>
        <ButtonMore />
        <ListComp />
        <ListFunc />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

`ButtonMore` will add items to the store when clicked. It has the action connected so it can dispatch it.

`ListComp` is connected to the list of items in the store and will `.map` them. In this case, the main purpose was to test the `key` property and see if only the new items would flash green.

`ListFunc` Will do the same as the one above but as a function component.

I wanted to drive this test since in the project I work on we are going crazy with performance issues now that the app is huge. We are thinking of moving away from redux but I don't think this option is good at all.

I expected some green flashes just on the new items displayed. But instead the whole screen will always flash when I change anything in the store.

EDIT: Let me add the example that shows the list of items from the store. I expected this to flash only the new items but instead it flashes the whole component:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const ListFunc = props => {
  return (
    <ul className="ListComp">
      {props.listItems.map((item, i) => {
        return <li key={`itemFunc_${i}`}>{item}</li>;
      })}
    </ul>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { listItems: state.reducer };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null
)(ListFunc);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React-Redux v6 [changed the internal implementation in several ways](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/11/react-redux-history-implementation/).  As part of that, the `connect()` wrapper components do actually re-render when an action is dispatched, even when your components don't.

For a variety of reasons, [we're changing that behavior as part of v7](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/1177), which is [now available as a beta](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v7.0.0-beta.0).

**update**

After looking at the code snippet you've posted: yes, I would *still* expect the example you've shown to cause both the list items *and* the list to re-render.  I can't say 100% for sure because you haven't shown your reducer, but assuming that one of the list items is updated properly, `state.reducer` *should* be a new array reference as well.  That will cause `ListFunc` to re-render.

Comment: Thank you very much for your swift response! It was a thing that was getting my mind blown for these past months. I will definitely give a read to all that tomorrow! Thanks a lot really!

Comment: After testing today, all body still flashes green, but not all the comps in it. I still see that the list does flash green as a whole and not the new items in the array, is this expected?

Comment: Tried also to go back to v6 and is the same behaviour as v7 in my example

Comment: Yep, you are absolutely right about the ListFunc and I understand the reason. But how about the App component flashing green. I see you point with the list, still only the 2 lists should flash, not the whole screen. And thanks again for keeping track of this question!

Comment: Not sure I can offer more advice at this point without seeing the entire app in action, like as a CodeSandbox or something.

Comment: Got it! It is the react paint flashing with the chrome dev tools paint flashing that are clashing together xD, now to see if I can get the function component to flash only the new items! Thanks for all the help!!!